# Why can't I see the contents of PC2 from PC1?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares, home-networking

```
PC1: Windows 10 Pro, paid for product key

PC2: Windows 10 Home, did not pay for product key, logged in with same Microsoft account as PC1, does not show the "Activate Windows" watermark in the bottom right corner
```

I did the following:

1. Made sure both PCs have their network connection set to Private (since both PCs are in my home)
2. For the Private profile, I made sure that both PCs have the "Turn on network discovery/Turn on automatic..." setting enabled and also "Turn on file and printer sharing" enabled
3. For the All Networks tab, I made sure to turn off password protected sharing for both PCs

On PC2, I can see PC1 and open the Users folder (and get to Desktop, Documents, etc..). On PC1, I can see PC2 but I **cannot** open the Users folder because the PC2 folder is empty. Why can't I explore the contents of PC2 from PC1?

Comment: Windows installations don’t typically have an “activation” watermark (or any watermark), only exception I know, are Insider Preview builds.  Are you running an Insider Preview build? Why are you expecting a watermark.

Comment: @Ramhound when you download and install Windows without a product key, normally it shows a watermark on the bottom right of your screen.

Comment: My comment was with regards to an activated copy of WIndows.  Your Windows 10 Home installation is clearly a OEM copy.

Comment: @Ramhound but Windows didn't come with this hardware. I had to install it using the Windows media creation tool that I downloaded from the internet.

Comment: Desktop or Laptop? Is the computer an OEM device?

Comment: @Ramhound they are both desktops. PC2 is composed of a motherboard, a CPU, and a blank SSD I had lying around.

Answer (score 0):

The "Users" folder is **not shared** by default. Windows only sets up a share for \Users when someone uses the "Give access to..." function on some folder for the first time.

To set up a share manually, right-click the \Users folder on PC2 and select "Properties → Sharing → Advanced Sharing → Share this folder".

(In the same "Advanced Sharing" dialog, also click "Permissions" and enable Change access to "Everyone". Be careful to not confuse this with the Security tab – *do not* grant any access through the "Security" tab, *only* through the "Share Permissions" tab.)

Comment: I followed your steps, but now PC2 isn't even showing up in PC1's network. Before it was showing up there but I couldn't see the Users folder, now the whole PC is completely gone.